# How to make dynamic menu in firefox addon for android?

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I wan to make item in main menu that will contains more items depends on some properties. I add `var menuID = window.NativeWindow.menu.add({callback:handleState, otherParams})` and make some sub items. But when i click to parent item `handleState` isn't call. So i can't update visibility of my items. How to subscribe on onClick event of main menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find how to fire callback so i use observer

```
nativeObserver: {
        observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            if (aTopic != "after-viewport-change") return;
            MenuHandler.handleNativeMenuState();
        }
    },
```